# when it sees utf-8 character jump another cell in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, utf-8

i have XML file and i'm reading from NSXMLParser

this is my code

```
import UIKit

class ***: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,NSXMLParserDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Liste: UITableView!

var strXMLData:String = ""
var currentElement:String = ""
var passData:Bool=false
var passName:Bool=false
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var userList: [S_Arsiv_Nesne] = []

func firstMethodforXML(){
    var urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: ServerBilgileri().Arsiv)!
    // Parse the XML
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
    parser.delegate = self

    var success:Bool = parser.parse()

    if success {
        println("parse success!")

        println(strXMLData)

    } else {
        println("parse failure!")
    }
    self.Liste.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.Liste.dataSource = self
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstMethodforXML()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.Liste.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.userList[indexPath.row].ARSIV_ADI

    return cell
}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    if elementName == "ARSIV_ADI" {
        passData = true
    }

}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
    if elementName == "ARSIV_ADI" {
        passData = false

    }
}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
    var Nesne: S_Arsiv_Nesne
    var deneme: String = string!
    if passData == true {
        Nesne = S_Arsiv_Nesne(ARSIV_ID: 0, ARSIV_ADI: string, ARSIV_KATEGORILER_ID: 0, ARSIV_ICERIK: "", ARSIV_YAZAR: "", ARSIV_TARIH: "", ARSIV_AKTIF: 0)
        userList.append(Nesne)
    }
}


}
```

this is my XML

```
<ARSIV_ADI>30 günle sağlık yardımı</ARSIV_ADI>
```

but 
screenshot is this

when it sees UTF-8 character like 'ü' jump another row and continue sentence how can i fix this ? I didn't explain some object in code but in my opinion it doesn't necessary .Thank you.

[image]

Comment: "ü" is not an "UTF-8 character". UTF-8 is an *encoding*, and all characters defined in the Unicode standard can be encoded as UTF-8. – What you probably mean is that "ü" is *not an ASCII character*.

Comment: yes you are right , thank you i found solution your answer